# Apache httpd 2.2 - How to transform value of a variable to remove part of the string

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have a variable coming in to Apache called "MELLON_NAME_ID" as part of mod_auth_mellon for SSO. It populates the variable with "DOMAIN\Username", and I need to populate the REMOTE_USER variable with just the "Username" portion of that. Is this possible?

Edit: It's also populating REMOTE_USER with the same value, so all I really need is to remove the "DOMAIN\" portion.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `MellonSetEnvNoPrefix "REMOTE_USER" "Username"`? Not sure about the `Username` variable but there must be one containing just the user that you can use in conjonction with `MellonSetEnvNoPrefix`

Comment: Thanks for the response Capsule, but I don't think that's really what I'm looking for. I don't need to translate a username to another, and don't want to have to have an entry for each username. I'm just looking to strip off the "DOMAIN\" portion of the value of REMOTE_USER every time. Seems like it's likely a mod_rewrite situation, but I'm not sure of the syntax yet.

Comment: I'd still double check the mod_auth_mellon documentation as you can pretty much define any Environment variable you want.

Answer (score 0):

To split the Name ID field, treat the header as a variable. Set it as a copy, then edit that copy using a regex (regular expression) substitution. FYI: I assume mod_headers is required for this.

Example:

```
RequestHeader set username "%{MELLON_NAME_ID}e"
RequestHeader set domain "%{MELLON_NAME_ID}e"
RequestHeader edit username "^.*\\\(.*)" "$1"
RequestHeader edit domain "^(.*)\\\.*" "$1"

Header set username "%{MELLON_NAME_ID}e"
Header set domain "%{MELLON_NAME_ID}e"
Header edit username "^.*\\\(.*)" "$1"
Header edit domain "^(.*)\\\.*" "$1"
```

Set `RequestHeader` if you want these headers to continue on, if for example, this is a proxy to another app that will need these set for its incoming request.

Set `Header` if you want these headers to return in the response to the browser (or whatever is expecting the response).

***NOTE:** The question says Apache 2.2, but I have only tested this on Apache 2.4.*